# Possibility of NPE on `keys.nextElement().contains()`

Tags: java

If `NullPointerException` occurs on the line `System.out.println(keys.nextElement().contains("Test"));` of the following code, what is the possible cause of it?

```java
private void print(Map<String, String> map) {
    Enumeration<String> keys = Collections.enumeration(map.keySet());
    while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(keys.nextElement().contains("Test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `keys.nextElement()` may be null

Comment: To add to the above comment, `hasMoreElements()` tells you whether there is a next element, but that next element could be `null` itself.

Comment: what data you are passing to Map?

Comment: Check `map.containsKey(null)`. - It indicates a bug IMHO on a map.put.

Comment: Unknown but the log indicate NPE occurs on this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background info: `HashMap` allows `null` keys ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html)). `HashTable` does not but it is also (probably) slower in use because it is thread-synchronized. So, I would advise that you need to take into account the possibility of `null` keys in your code, either avoid putting them in maps that you will pass to `print` or alter `print` to handle them.

You can make it happen with this code:

```
    private void test() {
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put(null, "Anything");
        print(m);
    }
```

if you can run a debugger it will be clear which call gives the NPE, if not, it's sometimes useful to split the expression like this

```
    private void print(Map<String, String> map) {
        Enumeration<String> keys = Collections.enumeration(map.keySet());
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String nextElement = keys.nextElement();
            boolean contains = nextElement.contains("Test");
            System.out.println(contains);
        }
    }
```

then you will see what line the exception is triggered by.

Comment: Why not just check null with if condition before `while` loop?

Comment: I didn't know that `HashMap` allows null keys and `keys.hasMoreElements()` is true ... Thank you.